# Change the background colour from white to transparent

Tags: wordpress, css

I need help with changing the background colour from white to transparent (Website URL is http://whosonlocation.com/). The website is a WordPress website.

The white background behind the menu and the logo should be transparent when page is loaded. But when it scrolls it turns white.

Thanks! I am newbie to Stack Overflow so any suggestions would help.

Comment: When you scroll, a new class is added to the navbar `is-sticky`. So if you want to set transparent colour to the menu container, you have to put `background-color: transparent` in the `.is-sticky .navbar-default` css rule.

Comment: Thanks.Tried that, it's not working. Should I add background color: transparent or opacity set to 0.2 ?

Comment: add an `!important` like @LoicTheAztec suggests...

Comment: Thanks! I tried this option. It makes the background transparent on scroll. I want the background transparent before page start scrolling...

Answer (score 1):

Inspecting your website it looks like the nav **is** transparent. If I'm understanding you correctly, you want the nav to overlap the header image.

At the moment the image is below the nav. One possible solution would be to add the following to `style.css` in your child theme:

```
.navbar {
    position: absolute;
}
```

Comment: Thanks A.Campbell. It really worked. Appreciate your help on this :-)

Answer (score 0):

Here is another solution:

Change the CSS (which is line number 754) in (style.css) file

.is-sticky .navbar-default {

```
background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
```

}